# In Sitecore, why does lifetime functionality work in preview mode but not in normal mode?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

The question is about the [Lifetime](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-standard-template-lifetime-section) section of Sitecore Standard Template

My case:

I have 2 versions of an item. In version 2, I set the lifetime **from**: `10:30 am` and **to**: `10:45 am`.

I go in `sc_mode=preview` and see version 2 being used, which is correct. Now I set the time @ `11:00 am` and version 1 is being used instead. This is working as intended.

Now I'm in `sc_mode=normal`. It is `10:40 am` and version 2 is being used. I wait until `10:46 am`, and version 2 is still being used. It has not switched to version 1. I've even tried to check the "hide version" checkbox on version 2, and it still shows that version.

FYI, I'm using the master database and `cacheHtml="false"` in the SiteDefinitions.config

How come? Is it only possible to test lifetime in preview mode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possibly a bug, but may be due to the fact that typically sites point at a published database with only one version so showing 'latest published version' is usually correct.

To have things work in 'normal' mode for most sites (which are not pointed at master) you would need a publish action to occur in order to update the valid version in the target database.

Comment: Definitely not a bug. OP is expecting the change to happen without publishing. Sitecore's UI is definitely a bit misleading here, but when using "Lifetime" like this, a publish action is expected for mode=normal - "web" DB would only ever hold one language version of any item.

Comment: Does this mean that lifetime is actually only being used in a publish action? There isn't some behind-the-scene thing, where the version will automatically change to another one?

Comment: Yes, the dates you specify are publishing restrictions. Back to the concept of 'one version in the web db', the publishing process has to determine which of the many possible versions should currently be in the web database.

This could be based on approval status in workflow, whether it is the latest approved version, or the publishing restrictions (dates) placed on it.

Publish runs, looks at versions, puts correct one into web database.

@MarkCassidy: I believe in this scenario Casper pointed live site at 'master' (live mode) which I would have thought would have worked correctly.